# How to put gradient in each word instead of in a paragraph as a whole in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want each word in a particular paragraph to have a gradient rather than let's say, the gradient running from one end of a paragraph to the other. So if i write the following :-

```
p {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#124, #095);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

What i get is the gradient running from one end of the para across the words to the other. 
But what i want is, each word of the para to have an individual gradient

**Edit: Added snippet...**

```css
p {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#124, #095);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet prosciutto chicken turkey, pork frankfurter tri-tip shoulder shankle pork belly andouille tongue. Short ribs porchetta sausage brisket picanha, pastrami sirloin salami bresaola filet mignon turkey tri-tip spare ribs. Capicola ham hock filet mignon sirloin, beef ribs rump short ribs. Short loin andouille jowl capicola beef filet mignon alcatra turducken jerky venison.</p>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle of what you have done so far?

Comment: I seem to remember that with CSS you cannot select 'content' to apply rules to it.  So, if you want to apply different CSS rules to each word, you might have to wrap each word with a tag and apply the rule to the tag itself. I.e. each word would wrap like `<i>word</i> <i>word2</i>` and then override the CSS for `i` to suit your needs - Side note: hmmm Bacon Ipsum (http://baconipsum.com/)

Comment: You could always write some javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `span` with class to sperate every paragraph
for example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>hello</title>
  <style media="screen">
    p {
      color: white;
    }
    .c1 {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#124, #095);
    }
    .c2 {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#095, #124);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p><span class="c1">text</span><span class="c2">another text</span>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your only CSS option is something incredibly unwieldy like this. (Which makes me think: Do you *really* need this effect for your site to be useful to your visitors?)

You might find a less unwieldy solution using JS, though.

```css
span {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#124, #095);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Bacon</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>amet</span> <span>prosciutto</span> <span>chicken</span> <span>turkey,</span> <span>pork</span> <span>frankfurter</span> <span>tri-tip</span> <span>shoulder</span> <span>shankle</span> <span>pork</span> <span>belly.</span> <span>Bacon</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>amet</span> <span>prosciutto</span> <span>chicken</span> <span>turkey,</span> <span>pork</span> <span>frankfurter</span> <span>tri-tip</span> <span>shoulder</span> <span>shankle</span> <span>pork</span> <span>belly.</span> <span>Bacon</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>amet</span> <span>prosciutto</span> <span>chicken</span> <span>turkey,</span> <span>pork</span> <span>frankfurter</span> <span>tri-tip</span> <span>shoulder</span> <span>shankle</span> <span>pork</span> <span>belly.</span></p>
```